# How to troubleshoot a crash message when details window will not display?

Tags: crash, log

I receive the below error message fairly regularly after loading into the OS. Whenever I click "Show Details" the secondary window opens for a brief moment, but then immediately the entire dialogue window closes so I can't read what it says.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9wbeS3d.png]

/var/log/apport.log is empty

How can I troubleshoot this problem further?

And for the record, even when I receive this message, the browser still seems to function as normal. I suspect it could be Vivaldi's internal updater trying to fire, but that's just a guess at this point.

Thank you for any input!

Comment: What if you run vivaldi from the terminal, by just typing in `vivaldi`? It would probably print something to the terminal

Comment: Hi @AmithKK, thanks for your help! Yes, you're right. Except in this instance, however, I receive the notice immediately after Linux finishes booting up. I'm not actively trying to launch the browser or anything, I just login to the OS and see the popup.

Comment: You receive the the same message when you launch it with the terminal as well right?

Comment: No, I don't receive an error when I launch it manually.

Comment: The same thing has been annoying me since I recently got a new laptop.

I discovered about `apport-cli` which is the command line version of this dialog.
You can optionally pass in the path to the crash report file with the -c flag.

So I ran `apport-cli -c PATH_TO_CRASH_FILE` and noticed it was saying 


`ERROR: gdb does not exist in the sandbox nor on the host` 

So after installing `gdb` everything worked as expected. Hope it helps

Comment: Excellent, thank you for sharing this @just_a_dude!